# How can I get rid of the "En" icon in the notification area?

Tags: notification-area

How can I get rid of the keyboard indicator icon in the Notification area?

I am running Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: what do you mean by En can you make a screen shot

Comment: you mean messaging icon ?

Comment: I think he means the keyboard language icon.

Comment: Do you have more than one keyboard layout installed?

Answer (score 7):

1. Click on **En**
2. Select **Text Entry Settings**
3. Uncheck **Show Current Input Source in Menu Bar** in the lower-left section.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- Open System Settings
- Click on the ‘Region and Language’ tile
- Uncheck the box next to ‘Show Current Input Source in Menu Bar’

And that’s it. The switcher is now hidden.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/10/turn-new-keyboard-applet-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about the "keyboard layout notification".

It allows you to easily switch between different keyboard layouts.

To disable it, right click on the icon, select *text Entry Settings*, you get a dialog, 
[image]
there at the bottom unselect *Show current input source in the menu bar*.